# convert html page to pdf

Tags: php, html, css, pdf

I tried to convert an simple html page to pdf.
For that I am using this lib:

https://tcpdf.org

This is my code:

```
<? $html ='
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Fira+Sans:wght@400;500;600&amp;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
        <style type="text/css">
        
        body {
              font-family: "Fira Sans", sans-serif;
            }
        
        
            table {
                width: 100% !important;
                font-size: 12px !important;
                border-spacing: 0px;
            }
        
            .tblPositionen {
                margin: 50px 0 50px 0;
            }
        
            .tblPositionen tbody td {
                padding: 20px 0;
                border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;   
                vertical-align: text-top;
                color: #656768;
                line-height: 20px;
            }
    
            .tblPositionen th {
                border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;   
                padding-bottom: 10px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-size: 11px;
            }
            
            .tblPositionen thead th {
                width: 10%;
            }
            
            .tblPositionen thead th:nth-child(1) {
                width: 60% !important;
            }
            
            .tblPositionen tfoot tr td {
                padding-top: 50px;
            }
            
            .tblPositionen tfoot tr td:nth-child(2), .tblPositionen tfoot tr td:nth-child(3) {
                border-bottom: 3px double #656768;
                line-height: 25px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            
            
            .tblFooter td {
                font-size: 11px;
                width: 33.3%;
                color: #656768;
                line-height: 20px;
                bottom: 0px;
            }
            
            .tblHeader {
                vertical-align: text-top;
                line-height: 25px;
                margin-bottom: 80px;
                color: #656768;
            }
            
            .tblHeader td:nth-child(1) {
                width: 70% !important;
            }
            
            .tblHeader td:nth-child(2){
                width: 30% !important;
            }
            
            .tblDokInfo td:nth-child(odd) {
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            
            .tblDokInfo td:nth-child(even) {
                color: #656768;
            }
            
            
    
            
            h1 {
                margin-bottom: 0px !important;
            }
            
            .tblAbschluss {
                color: #656768;
                line-height: 20px;
                margin-bottom: 100px;
            }
            
        

        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    
    <table class="tblAbsender" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td style="font-size: 11px;"><b>Name</b> | Street | City</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table class="tblHeader" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td>
                [Anrede]<br />
                [Vorname] [Nachname]<br />
                [Straße Hausnummer]<br />
                [PLZ] [Ort]
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="tblDokInfo" cellpadding="5">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rechnungsnummer</td>
                        <td>[automatisch]</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Kundennummer</td>
                        <td>123456</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Rechnungsdatum</td>
                        <td>01.01.1990</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Leistungsdatum</td>
                        <td>01.01.1990</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <table cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td><h1>Rechnung</h1></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vielen Dank für Ihren Auftrag. Wir berechnen Ihnen folgende Leistungen:</td>
        </tr>
        </table>

         
    <table class="tblPositionen">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="left"><b>Bezeichnung</b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Menge</b></th>
                <th align="center"><b>Einheit</b></th>
                <th align="right"><b>Einzelpreis</b></th>
                <th align="right"><b>Preis</b></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    Vor Ort Service<br />
                    Beschreibung
                </td>
                <td align="center">1,00</td> 
                <td align="center">Fahrt</td>
                <td align="right">10,00 €</td>
                <td align="right">10,00 €</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    Vor Ort Service<br />
                    Beschreibung
                </td>
                <td align="center">1,00</td> 
                <td align="center">Fahrt</td>
                <td align="right">10,00 €</td>
                <td align="right">10,00 €</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                  <td colspan="2"></td>
                  <td colspan="2" align="left"><b>Rechnungsbetrag </b></td>
                  <td align="right"><b>10,00 €</b></td>
              </tr>     
        </tfoot>
    </table>
         
         
    <table class="tblAbschluss" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                Zahlbar innerhalb von 14 Tagen nach Erhalt der Rechnung.<br />
                <br />
                Gemäß §19 Abs. 1 UStG wird keine Umsatzsteuer berechnet.<br />
                <br />
                Wir freuen uns auf die weitere Zusammenarbeit.
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>';




require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->Output( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Rechnung.pdf', 'F');

?>
```

My HTML looks like this:

[image]

But my PDF file ugly like this:

[image]

Any idea where is my mistake?
Or can you tell me another lib which will works better?

Comment: You can try with the `wkhtmltopdf` library.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid

Comment: @mplungjan I guess that this is not the main problem :/

Comment: @Mainul Hasan how can I use it with php?

Comment: It's another library for generating pdf where you don't need to pass lots of arguments. Check their documentation and Github.

Comment: sorry but there I can only read stuff about c+ nothing about php

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your custom css is not taken into account like you want ;)

In general it's tricky to create PDF from HTML ... I made the best experience using [DOMPDF](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) (PHP solution, in need of dependencies) or [wkthmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) (needs installation on the server).

Dunno about the external font ... try different approaches in CSS which are supported by tcpdf for the spacing, like height instead of padding.

Also, tcpdf is kind of outdated, and they state that they are working on a new version.